# Ability to choose from a list of compute clusters to run a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am trying to create something like google colab notebooks. Google cola has a way to select the compute cluster I want to run my notebook on. [screenshot from google colab]

Are there any extensions available on JupyterLab that can help achieve this? I want to be able to choose a cluster, I want to run my notebook on. Any other notebook frameworks, I should look into?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you are talking about changing `python` runtime version then yes it is possible in Jupyter to have multiple versions. Whereas if it's about Hardware Acceleration option then it is NO - to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Hey, nobody knows what you are asking.  You need to paste links or other examples.